# How to get the type of a subterm when you're building a match

Tags: coq

My general question is: is there an easy way to incrementally build up a definition in Coq when I'm not familiar with the type of what I'm working with?

Consider one definition of the natural numbers in Coq, from `Coq.Narith.BinNat`

```
Definition discr n : { p:positive | n = pos p } + { n = 0 }.
```

Now, to me it's a little confusing what this term looks like. Suppose I'm trying to extract this positive `p` from the definition. My first try failed:

```
Require Import Coq.Narith.BinNat.
Fail Definition NToPos (x : N) : positive :=
  match N.discr x with
  | inright HO   => 1 
  | inleft Hpos  => Hpos
  end.
(*
Error:
In environment
x : N
Hpos : {p : positive | x = N.pos p}
The term "Hpos" has type "{p : positive | x = N.pos p}"
while it is expected to have type "positive".
*)
```

Well... okay. Now I know my basic misunderstanding is with the notation `{p : positive | x = N.pos p}`, but where do I go from here?

My question is, is there a better way to understand a definition such as `N.discr`? What I think I want is the following:

```
Definition NToPos (x : N) : positive :=
  match N.discr x with
  | inright HO   => 1 
  | inleft Hpos  => (* Please tell me how to further destruct Hpos *)
  end.
```

Comment: I think you should check out (1) Program Definition (2) refine (3) evars (including the `evar` tactic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, to decipher a notation, you can ask something like

```
Locate "{ x | p }".
```

In this case, this figures out what `{ p : positive | n = pos p }` means (you replace the "replaceable" parts of the notation with (meta)variables). It gives

```
Notation "{ x  |  P }" := sig (fun x => P)
```

Now the name `sig` can be used to get more information.

```
Print sig.
(*
Inductive sig (A : Type) (P : A -> Prop) : Type :=
  exist : forall x : A,
          P x -> {x : A | P x}
Arguments exist [A]%type_scope _%function_scope
*)
```

Which tells you that you need to match `Hpos` against `exist _ p Hpos` (the `Arguments` say that `A` is implicit and that `P` is explicit, but `P` (as a parameter) is already fixed by the type of the scrutinee and must be ignored, and the remaining arguments, `x : A` and the `P x`, need to be named).

Alternatively,

```
Unset Printing Notations. (* In CoqIDE, you're told to set this from the view menu instead *)
Check N.discr.
(* Shows you that the notation stands for sig *)
```

And then continue as before.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured this out by checking `Print N.discr` and observing:

```
N.discr = 
fun n : N =>
match n as n0 return ({p : positive | n0 = N.pos p} + {n0 = 0%N}) with
| 0%N => inright eq_refl
| N.pos p =>
    inleft (exist (fun p0 : positive => N.pos p = N.pos p0) p eq_refl)
end
     : forall n : N, {p : positive | n = N.pos p} + {n = 0%N}
```

and seeing that the case I want is `exist (fun p0 : positive => N.pos p = N.pos p0) p eq_refl`. Then, `exist` is the key function. From that I was able to correctly guess `inleft (exists p Hpos)` would work:

```
Definition NToPos (x : N) : positive :=
  match N.discr x with
  | inright HO            => 1 
  | inleft (exist p Hpos) => p
  end.
```